# How can I measure the amount of physical memory use of a function?

Tags: c#, memory

Function is not in my control, so I cannot calculate by looking at the code. It inputs a file and behaves differently for different kind of files; and I'm trying to predict the physical memory it will require. I'm trying to find a correlation between files and the memory requirement of the function. Later, I'll use this info to determine number of threads to be created that each will call this function.

Using Process.GetCurrentProcess() and [Process.PrivateMemorySize64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.privatememorysize64?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Diagnostics_Process_PrivateMemorySize64) I can get the difference between total memory use before and after calling the function. Since there is no memory leak, I get this value as zero, so it is not an information for me. What I really need is to learn the maximum memory used during the execution of the function.

[Process.PeakWorkingSet64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.peakworkingset64?view=netframework-4.8) gives the maximum amount of total physical memory use since the start of the application.

Is there a way to **reset** the value of **PeakWorkingSet64** to zero, so that I get the difference between the initial and the function's maximum memory use? Or is there any other way to measure what I want?

**Edit**

I've come up with this dirt solution, but it seems to be working. It measures process memory on every 100 milliseconds from a different thread. Any comment 
or a better solution would be very appreciated.

```
        private static int _no;
        private static double getCurrentMemoryInMB(System.Diagnostics.Process proc)
        {
            GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); GC.Collect();
            proc.Refresh();
            return proc.PrivateMemorySize64 / 1024d / 1024d;
        }
        private static void measureMemoryUse(Action action, string processingFileName)
        {            
            double before = 0d, after;
            bool killTask = false;
            double peak = 0d;
            using (System.Diagnostics.Process proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess())
                try
                {
                    before = getCurrentMemoryInMB(proc);
                    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        while (!killTask)
                        {
                            peak = Math.Max(peak, getCurrentMemoryInMB(proc));
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                        }
                    });
                    action();
                }
                finally
                {
                    killTask = true;
                    after = getCurrentMemoryInMB(proc);

                    double diff = peak - before;

                    var fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(processingFileName);
                    double fileSize = fi.Length / 1024d / 1024d;
                    string fileName = fi.Name;

                    string fnReport = @"C:\....\report.csv";
                    if (!File.Exists(fnReport))
                    {
                        _no = 0;
                        File.AppendAllLines(fnReport, new string[] { "#;before (mb);peakMem (mb);after (mb);diff (mb);fileSize (mb);diff/fileSize;fileName" });
                    }

                    File.AppendAllLines(fnReport, new string[] { string.Format("{0};{1};{2};{3};{4};{5};{6};{7}", ++_no, before, peak, after, diff, fileSize, diff / fileSize, fileName) });
                }
        }
```

Comment: Do you measure from the application itself or is external profiler OK? Something like https://memprofiler.com/ or https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/ .

Comment: I try to measure it in the application itself. I use Redgate profiler and its great, but I couldn't figure out how to find which file allocate how much memory. I'm trying to write a test code to measure that.

Comment: Why reset to zero? Just remember used memory as variable before start and then subtract that from the final used memory. The problem is that GC can run at any point and ruin the measurement.

Comment: @Euphoric that subtraction gives zero, because there is no memory-leak. I'm not trying to measure the memory leak. I call GC.Collect before measuring.

Comment: Provided your function doesn't spawn new threads itself, there's [`GC.GetAllocatedBytesForCurrentThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.gc.getallocatedbytesforcurrentthread). This measures total allocation and not peak use, but the two can be considered identical in cases where the GC doesn't run (over which you have no explicit control anyway). You cannot convincingly extrapolate these results to memory use when running from many threads, though -- the only safe approach is to measure actual scenarios.